# USB drive WriteFile to sectors outside volume

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, usb, usb-drive

I'm developing c++ WinAPI program to write data on my USB drive directly with `CreateFile` by the Volume{GUID} and `WriteFile` functions as dozens of examples do. As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365748(v=vs.85).aspx) in Remarks:

> A write on a volume handle will succeed if the volume does not have a
>   mounted file system, or if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The sectors to be written to are boot sectors.
> - The sectors to be written to reside outside of file system space.
> - You have explicitly locked or dismounted the volume by using `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` or `FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME`.
> - The volume has no actual file system. (In other words, it has a RAW file system mounted.)

I want write 100Mb of data on USB smoothly without any unmounting. So I've tried two of the cases from above.

1. The second case: writing outside of the file system (I've extended the number of sectors per partition without extending FAT32 table), but it doesn't work without unmounting!
2. The fourth case: write on the volume without any file system (unformatted). But it also doesn't work without unmounting!!!

Also I've tried to create the second partition (that is invisible for Windows) with/without file system and write directly there by the offset from the end of first partition, but also unsuccessfully: I can not read or write there.

So, if anybody knows ANSWER TO THE ONE OF THE QUESTIONS at least:

1. How can I create sectors inside the partition outside
   the file system?
2. Is there an ability to write smoothly on USB directly?
3. Also can I write in Windows to the second partition on USB without
   playing around with drivers, NTCreateFile and other deep functions?

Comment: This can only be for malware, right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, it's just for academical purposes :) I've just dived into the USB and FAT32 format and tried to check if msdn remark is correct..

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it actually worked, but you don't realize that you're bypassing Windows. That means Windows will not have noticed what you did. So if you use Windows to check what you did, it will not report a change.

To address the individual sub-questions: A normal file system fills the entire partition, so you can't. Your functions write smoothly to USB, that's not the problem. And no, Windows normally treats USB as unpartitioned storage.

Comment: Thank's for your answer!
I use HxD to watch changes on my drive, but I see that nothing has happened. Moreover WriteFile and ReadFile return 0 amount of written/read bytes. 
Is it right: when I increase the amount of partition sectros, the file system automatically fills that space? But then what does Microsoft mean by "The sectors to be written to reside outside of file system space"?
So, I can not write smoothly if I use mounted partition. I can only write if it's locked or unmounted...
Ok, so I can only write on the visible partition?